# Please consider leaving feedback on votes for new users

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, new-users

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824880/how-to-remove-a-partition-on-a-hard-disk#824893) where two new users had answered and both of them got downvoted.

Now I get why not everyone comments on their votes but I really think if you are dealing with rep 1 users who are making an effort, it is counter productive and may lead to these users felling disgruntled and unwelcome.

A simple comment to explain and linking the help section would go a long way to help these users contribute quality posts.

Of course, this is my opinion and I can't tell anyone to do anything but these users are the 10k users of tomorrow and we should help them, rather than punish them, very few of us would be here now if we were not offerd feedback on our early posts..

This is just my 2 cents.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  I personally got ahead on the site with helpful comments by high-rep users who explained what's wrong with my answer in a polite and respectful manner

Comment: Same for me too @Serg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great proposal. I think when down-voting anyone you should give a comment. Indeed I think the software suggests you do so.

We all started with rep zero. We are all human beings with feelings and especially on this platform we should be professional with manners, decorum, proper etiquette and appropriate empathy to others.

I've noticed a occasional condescension from some in the >10k club but maybe they were having an off day. It's really not something you can flag because we live in a free speech society on the internet.

Worse perhaps is a heavy handed mod with the powers to simply delete your post without posting a comment and giving you the chance to say "oops sorry I didn't see that answer had my answer buried inside, I'll go ahead and delete my answer".

Most of us live busy lives can be exposed to extraordinary stress from time to time (ok most times for some) and make mistakes.

Do unto others....